# Updating single item in GridView.Builder() without rebuilding whole tree

Tags: flutter, gridview, flutter-layout, flutter-provider

I am trying to update a single image in my gridview of images when a user taps on the image but whenever I update a single element of array, it updates the entire gridview. This itself is not bad but since user will be selecting multiple images, it does not look ideal or good. I would appreciate it if someone can guide me to update single element of gridview without updating the entire widget

I am using provider for my state management but I have also tried it with setState. I have include all the code of the gridview file but let me know if you need for info.

Thanks

```
      return Consumer<RemoverList>(
      builder: (context, data, child) {
        return WillPopScope(
          onWillPop: () async {
            data.remover.clear();
            data.removerBool.clear();
            // Provider.of<RemoverList>(context).remover.clear();
            return true;
          },
          child: Scaffold(
            body: Container(
              height: height,
              width: width,
              color: Theme.of(context).backgroundColor,
              child: SafeArea(
                child: Column(
                  children: [
                    GestureDetector(
                      onTap: () {
                        Navigator.pushNamed(context, 'options');
                      },
                      child: Container(
                        height: height * 0.05,
                        width: width * 0.95,
                        margin: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 20),
                        decoration: BoxDecoration(
                            borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(2),
                            border: Border.all(color: Colors.white)),
                        child: Center(
                          child: Text(
                            widget.album.name,
                            style: const TextStyle(
                                color: Colors.white,
                                fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                                fontSize: 25),
                          ),
                        ),
                      ),
                    ),
                    Expanded(
                        child: Container(
                      padding: const EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(0, 5, 0, 5),
                      // color: Colors.green,
                      width: width * 0.95,
                      decoration: BoxDecoration(
                          color: Colors.grey,
                          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(5)),
                      child: GridView.builder(
                          itemCount: widget.album.images.length,
                          gridDelegate:
                              const SliverGridDelegateWithFixedCrossAxisCount(
                                  mainAxisSpacing: 5,
                                  crossAxisSpacing: 5,
                                  crossAxisCount: 3),
                          itemBuilder: (context, i) {
                            data.generateRemoverList(widget.album.images);
                            var image = Uint8List.fromList(widget
                                .album.images[i].image['data']
                                .cast<int>());
                            return GestureDetector(
                                onLongPress: () {
                                  // data.tapped(i);
                                  if (data.removerBool.isNotEmpty) {
                                    if (data.removerBool[i] == true) {
                                      setState(() {
                                        data.removerBool[i] = false;
                                      });
                                    } else {
                                      setState(() {
                                        data.removerBool[i] = true;
                                      });
                                    }
                                  }
                                  print(data.removerBool[i]);
                                  print(data.remover);
                                  setState(() {
                                    active = true;
                                  });
                                  data.addToList(
                                      widget.album.images[i].originalName);
                                },
                                onTap: () {
                                  if (active == false) {
                                    Navigator.push(context,
                                        MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) {
                                      return OpenImage(unit: image);
                                    }));
                                  } else if (active == true) {
                                    data.addToList(
                                        widget.album.images[i].originalName);
                                    print(data.remover);
                                    data.removerBool[i] = !data.removerBool[i];
                                    // data.tapped(i);
                                  }
                                  // data.tapped(i);
                                  // print(data.removerBool[i]);
                                },
                                child: Container(
                                  decoration: BoxDecoration(
                                      color: Colors.black,
                                      image: DecorationImage(
                                          image: MemoryImage(image),
                                          fit: BoxFit.cover)),
                                  child: Center(
                                    child: data.remover.contains(
                                            widget.album.images[i].originalName)
                                        ? const Icon(
                                            Icons.check_box_rounded,
                                            color: Colors.black,
                                          )
                                        : Container(),
                                  ),
                                ));
                          }),
                    )),
                    Container(
                      width: width * 0.95,
                      margin: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 10),
                      alignment: Alignment.bottomCenter,
                      child: Column(
                        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.end,
                        children: [
                          Row(
                            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                            children: [
                              Container(
                                width: width * 0.45,
                                child: ElevatedButton(
                                    onPressed: () {},
                                    child: const Text('Add Photos')),
                              ),
                              Container(
                                width: width * 0.45,
                                child: ElevatedButton(
                                    onPressed: () {},
                                    child: const Text('Remove Seleted')),
                              )
                            ],
                          ),
                          Row(
                            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                            children: [
                              Container(
                                width: width * 0.45,
                                child: ElevatedButton(
                                    onPressed: () {},
                                    child: const Text('Save')),
                              ),
                              Container(
                                width: width * 0.45,
                                child: ElevatedButton(
                                    onPressed: () {},
                                    child: const Text('Delete Album')),
                              )
                            ],
                          )
                        ],
                      ),
                    )
                  ],
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ),
        );
      },
    );
  }
}
```